# Is there a way to make code under with statement execute multiple times in python?

Tags: python, decorator, with-statement

I know, that this would probably break a number of rules/guides, but python surprised me before and that thing might still be possible.

Let's say there is a piece of code:

```
print("before")
with multiply_context(4):
    print("while")
print("after")
```

Is there a way a way to implement `multiply_context` that code above will have the same output as the code below:

```
print("before")
for _ in range(4):
    print("while")
print("after")
```

Namely, can I leverage `with` statement to run a piece of code under it multiple times?

Comment: I'm curious: what's the use case you're after?

Comment: Don't think so; the context manager (what `with` is built out of) doesn't directly access the code in the `with` body.

Comment: the code under my context is creating a set of operation-objects to be executed by a framework. It would be a lot cleaner to recreate them multiple times by re-running user code than trying to track and duplicate all the sideeffects they produce.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a `with` context manager, as you only get hooks for entering and exiting. You would need to, I don't know, save the stack trace on entering and restoring it on exiting? Which I'm pretty sure is not possible within normal Python. A function decorator would be the right construct for something like that I think.

Comment: You can parse the source code directly (use the indentation to figure out where the with statement exits) and modify it if you want to create some abomination functionality. Or you can use a decorator with parameters which most people would go for.